# Who creates beans in a spring web application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I know that in a standalone application I create one of the application context instances which in turn creates the beans from conf files. But I can not see any such code in dispatched servlet. How then are the beans created in a web application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html) creates an `ApplicationContext` (by delegating to `ContextLoader`) and stores it in the servlet context.

So you have to map the `ContextLoaderListener` is a `<listener>` in `web.xml`

Then, of course, that `ApplicationContext` (`WebApplicationContext` in this case) creates the beans.